# What was Izumi doing in the Central City railway station?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

While watching ep. 9 of *Brotherhood*, I noticed that when Winry came to Central City railway station and started looking for someone, Izumi and her husband were walking behind her:

Picture from FMA brotherhood.

[image: Izumi, Sig, and Winry at train station, *Brotherhood*]

After that I tried for this scene in the 2003 series, and in ep. 23 I have found this scene where they were reading something at the Central railway station:

Picture from Anime FMA 2003

[image: Izumi and Sig at Central, 2003]

So my question is: what might Izumi and her husband be doing there? Do they usually travel like this, or might there be any sort of work they had to do there? Is it also possible that it is an error (like they didn't want to put those characters there)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Izumi was looking for Ed and Al. She had been hearing rumors that they had joined the State Alchemists and become dogs of the military.

In the 2003 anime we see that Izumi and Sig are talking to Mustang before Ed, Al and Winry leave Central. At the end of Episode 26 the two have caught up to them in Rush Valley. If I recall correctly, in the next episode Izumi reveals that she came after them to "re-educate" her wayward students.

The Welcome to Central City poster that we see Izumi and Sig look at to me looks like a directory of sorts. You see Izumi is looking at a list so she is probably looking up places to search.

I would assume it's the same in Brotherhood (I can't remember exactly if their reunion was the same) because in both series Ed has made a name for himself as a State Alchemist and in both Izumi shows her dislike towards the military. There is no doubt she would hear about the "State Alchemist and Hero of the people Edward Elric".

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in the manga, the brothers seek out Izumi themselves. Not sure if Izumi was trying to find them prior to their actual reunion, or if she and her husband were just travelling and we were just given a cameo or Easter egg. (Seeing how she first met the brothers while travelling, the latter isn't implausible.)